# Why does the value of BigDecimal not match the value supplied to it in the constructor?

Tags: java, system, bigdecimal

I have a `BigDecimal` in Java. I know it is a value which would not be used in most cases. When this code is executed my command console prints out the following; `1789984896489654735783157941777104561834014693972171030528`. This is not the full `BigDecimal`. My question is why does it not print the full number?

```
BigDecimal bD = new BigDecimal(1789984896489654689748964897484894895484896546845987465874.54644685486451845867467986798679864598764589459468746587946578945);
System.out.println(bD);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the constructor that you are using: `BigDecimal(double)`. The big long string of digits gets converted to Java's `double`, which does not have nearly enough precision for what you are trying to put into `BigDecimal`.

You need to use the `BigDecimal(String)` constructor instead:

```
BigDecimal bD = new BigDecimal("1789984896489654689748964897484894895484896546845987465874.54644685486451845867467986798679864598764589459468746587946578945");
//                             ^                                                                                                                            ^
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/zz0Fuf)